# Running Python Scripts from Command Line with Pypy Interpreter

Tags: python, command-line, path, pypy

So, I have installed the pypy pre-built interpreter to my home folder in windows; however, it only allows me to execute python scripts through the interpreters interface (similar to IDLE). I would like to extend this functionality to the cmd line in windows by putting something referencing the pypy interpreter to my system's PATH, however, I cannot find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add folder with pypy.exe to your PATH. [Here](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/man/pypy.1.html) you can read documentation about pypy command line.

Answer (score 0):

to add to your path just open your start menu

right click on "Computer"

select "Properties"

click option for "Advanced System Settings"

click option for "environmental Variables"

change the one named "PATH" to include the folder that you need